# Whereto put "plugins" in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, directory, plugins

I am currently developing/hacking an image analyzing/transforming tool.
The filters therein will be loaded at runtime using dlopen&co.

My question is where do *nix tools usually put plugins (*.so files) when installed?

```
bin/program
lib/program/plugins/thisandthat.so
```

maybe?

Secondly how do I use it and where do I put it during development without installing it. (this is probably the tricky part)

I want to avoid shell-scripts if possible.

thanks in regard
Ronny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout seems sensible. You can, for instance, look in current directory, look up environment variable or command line switch during development. It depends on the details of your development environment and workflow.

Answer (score 5):

Usually /usr/lib/programmname should be a good spot

During development I'd create a command line paramter to specify the plugin search path and just leave the plugins in the build-dir for example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
/usr/lib/program/*.so
```

Answer (score 3):

A good guide for choosing is [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).
Most Linux distribuitions use this standard.

Here is a very short summary.

Place application binary in:
/usr/bin/progname, /usr/local/bin/progname or /opt/progname

Place plugins or library files in:
/usr/lib/progname, /usr/local/lib/progname or /opt/progname/lib

Place host configuration for the application in:
/etc/progname or /etc/opt/progname

Place user configuration in:
$HOME/.progname

Place application manual page in:
/usr/shar/man/man1/

There is separate hierachy for /var. As an example use /var/log/progname for logging.

In responce to caf's comment. I find it very usefull to choose target directory at compile time. Using a $PREFIX also makes it easy to separate devellopment build's from shippment.
Most use /usr/progname, /usr/lib/progname and /etc/progname

Comment: so really `$PREFIX/lib/program/`, where `PREFIX` might be `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/opt` or even `/home/foo`.

Comment: I would only use /opt for library files if the entire application is installed in /opt.
I use $HOME/.program/ for user specific configuration. The similar to how ssh use $HOME/.ssh

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear - typically `PREFIX` would be set at build time, so yes the entire app would be installed in various locations under it, like `$PREFIX/bin/` and `$PREFIX/share/doc/`.

Comment: +1, I have been looking for a guide like that for a long time!

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget:

```
$HOME/.program/
```